# Replace duplicate records to null in the column

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query for the following output,please help

## transaction Table

```
 id   name    customer  product  amount    ref_no

  1  raja     xyz       abc      100      q123

  2  raja     xyz       def       100     q123

  3  raja     xyz       ddd       200     q123

  4  rajesh   xyz       abc       100     q124

  5  rajesh   xyz       def       200     q124
```

## output

```
name  customer  product  amount
raja   xyz       abc      100
                 def      100 
                 ddd      200
rajesh xyz       abc      100
                 def      200
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: Why do you want to have null in those fields?

Comment: no primary key in the table hun ?

Comment: Your requirement doesn't conform to how RDBMS stores data. It's all about representation of the data which provided by this simple query `SELECT name,customer,product,amount FROM transaction`

Comment: primary key is there@AbhikChakraborty

Comment: First, your question has nothing to do with primary keys or anything of the kind. Second, there are some options to implement that. The first thing I would try is to use a CASE clause for the first two fields along with a local variable that would have the value of the last found name. You might need to create a nested select. This is just an idea without checking it, which is left to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one:

```
set @cnt = 0;
select
case when check_cnt is null then NULL else name end as `name`,
case when check_cnt is null then NULL else customer end as customer,product,amount,ref_no from
(select  rcount,name,customer,product,amount,ref_no,
case when rcount!=1 then null else rcount end as check_cnt
 from
(select @cnt:=if(@cnt=1,customer,ROW_COUNT()+1)as rcount,
name,customer,product,amount,ref_no from `transaction`) as a) as a
```

result:

[image]

[image]

New result same as your above sample output:

This is the final one:

```
select
case when a.min_id is null then NULL else b.name end as `name`,
case when a.min_id is null then NULL else customer end  as `customer`
,product,amount,ref_no from
(select min(id) as min_id,count(1),name from `transaction` group by name) as a
right JOIN
(select id, name,customer,product,amount,ref_no from `transaction`) as b
on a.min_id = b.id
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much @reds

Comment: thanks for your reply...if the column  name repeat more than twice it wont works proper..i have updated the sample  input .thanks in advance

Comment: That final one will resolve your problem.. try to take a look.. i update the answer above.. good luck

Comment: Thanks for your response got it